# Using CloudSQL private IP access from two different VPCs in the same project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a cloudSQL instance that is connected to the default VPC and has the private service access and privateIP setup for the default vpc.  I've created a new VPC to migrate applications to and I want to connect to the same cloudSQL database instance.  Is it possible to connect both VPCs to the same cloudSQL instance or do I have to work around this?  The two VPCs are *not peered to each other but I would like the applications that run in each VPC to be able to connect to the same cloudSQL instance while I migrate applications to the new VPC.

Everything I've read and tried seems like it's not possible.  If this is true, my migration plan is to connect the new VPC to cloudSQL via the publicIP temporarily.  Then once the default VPC is depricated I can change the private networking connection to the new VPC and then connect via the privateIP again.  Does that sound like a good solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Accessing Cloud SQL from two different VPC is not possible at the moment. There is a [PIT](https://issuetracker.google.com/142829575) as Feature Request has been opened. Please feel free to post there if you have any questions and concern on this issue.

Comment: There is a WA might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/61014111/11866104

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  It's good to have this clarification.  What about moving peering from one VPC to another is there anything to watch out for when attempting to do that?